# How to solve , error if 'domain' in method_res: TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

i'm running this code, which is supposed to remove element that meet a certain requirement from a list while iterating through it:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('stage_a_id','selection_id','cause_id','location_id','batch_id')
def _change_domain_causeid(self):

    if self:
        self.stage_a_id=self.selection_id.stage_id
        arrTransferSeed = []
        if self.stage_a_id.code == 'PN':
            batchTransferPn =self.env['estate.nursery.batchline'].search([('batch_id.id','=',self.batch_id.id),('location_id.id','!=',False)])
            for a in batchTransferPn:
                arrTransferSeed.append(a.location_id.id)
        elif self.stage_a_id.code == 'MN':
            batchTransferMn = self.env['estate.nursery.transfermn'].search([('batch_id.id','=',self.batch_id.id)])
            for b in batchTransferMn:
                stockLocation = self.env['estate.block.template'].search([('id','=',b.location_mn_id[0].id)])
                stock= self.env['stock.location'].search([('id','=',stockLocation.inherit_location_id[0].id)])
                idlot= self.env['estate.nursery.batch'].search([('id','=',self.batch_id.id)])
                qty = self.env['stock.quant'].search([('lot_id.id','=',idlot[0].lot_id.id),('location_id.id','=',stock[0].id)])
                if qty[0].qty > 0:
                    arrTransferSeed.append(b.location_mn_id.id)
        return {
            'domain': {'cause_id': [('stage_id.id', '=',self.stage_a_id.id)],
                       'location_id': [('id','in',arrTransferSeed)]},
        }
    return True
```

and show error like this :

```
argument of type 'bool' is not iterable odoo
```

how can i resolved my problems?

Answer (score 0):

This erreur comes when you call a function with null values .

so check every variable if it  has a value before you do something with it:

```
if variable_name : 
    use_value_ofvariable_name_in_your_code_always_play_safe
```

and the domain sould be like this :
 always use cast  int() in the domains to be sure.

```
'domain': {'cause_id': [('stage_id', '=',int(self.stage_a_id.id))],
                       'location_id': [('id','in',arrTransferSeed)]},
```

Comment: oke. i solved my problem, my problem show when i use readonly_bypass in v9. and my value with context not saved in DB. and then my function showing error with null value

Comment: at least give me a vote lol , ok you right when you make a field in the form realdonly when you change it's value with a function and try to store it will not find it if you can use invisible="true" instead of realdonly invisible value are stored

Comment: this a a problem in odoo 9.0  readonly value will not be stored i used invisible for this metter because i don't want the user to update the value

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, and i found solution using readonly_bypass for odoo 9.0. this link for readonly_bypass https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/9.0/web_readonly_bypass/

Comment: you celcom we are here to eachothers so tell me i didn't hear about readonly_bypass can give me an exemple where  to put it in the field of the view or the field declaration in the class